# Model Class Fallthrough

Tags: model, configuration, class, module

I created a new model class called `Company_CatalogSearch_Model_System_Config_ListSort` which I used to create a copy of the Product Listing Sort By option from the catalog module, just for the catalogsearch module. My `congif.xml` looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CatalogSearch>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_CatalogSearch>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <result>Company_CatalogSearch_Block_Result</result>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <catalogsearch>
                <class>Company_CatalogSearch_Model</class>
            </catalogsearch>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

This was just fine as long as Magento was only trying to access `Company_CatalogSearch_Model_System_Config_ListSort` (my new model.) But as soon as it tried to use any other models, such as `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query` I would get an error:

```
ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Company\CatalogSearch\Model\Query.php' for inclusion
```

I tried many, many different combinations of rewrites and more specific model definitions in the `config.xml` file but in the end the only way I could get this work was to either:

**Option 1:**
Create a file with a blank class for each model which extended the Mage class, like so:

```
<?php
class Graybox_Catalogsearch_Model_Query extends Mage_Catalogsearch_Model_Query
{
    // This is just here because it has to be
}
```

**Option 2:**
Create a rewrite for each and every one of the model classes for the catalogsearch module, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CatalogSearch>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_CatalogSearch>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <result>Company_CatalogSearch_Block_Result</result>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <catalogsearch>
                <class>Company_CatalogSearch_Model</class>
                <rewrite>
                    <advanced>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced</advanced>
                    <fulltext>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext</fulltext>
                    <fulltext_observer>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext_Observer</fulltext_observer>
                    <indexer_fulltext>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext</indexer_fulltext>
                    <layer>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer</layer>
                    <layer_filter_attribute>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
                    <mysql4_advanced>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Advanced</mysql4_advanced>
                    <mysql4_advanced_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Advanced_Collection</mysql4_advanced_collection>
                    <mysql4_fulltext>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Fulltext</mysql4_fulltext>
                    <mysql4_fulltext_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Fulltext_Collection</mysql4_fulltext_collection>
                    <mysql4_fulltext_engine>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Fulltext_Engine</mysql4_fulltext_engine>
                    <mysql4_indexer_fulltext>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Indexer_Fulltext</mysql4_indexer_fulltext>
                    <mysql4_query_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Query_Collection</mysql4_query_collection>
                    <mysql4_search_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Search_Collection</mysql4_search_collection>
                    <mysql4_query>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Query</mysql4_query>
                    <resource_advanced>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced</resource_advanced>
                    <resource_advanced_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced_Collection</resource_advanced_collection>
                    <resource_fulltext>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext</resource_fulltext>
                    <resource_fulltext_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection</resource_fulltext_collection>
                    <resource_fulltext_engine>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine</resource_fulltext_engine>
                    <resource_helper_mysql4>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4</resource_helper_mysql4>
                    <resource_indexer_fulltext>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Indexer_Fulltext</resource_indexer_fulltext>
                    <resource_query_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Query_Collection</resource_query_collection>
                    <resource_search_collection>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Search_Collection</resource_search_collection>
                    <resource_query>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Query</resource_query>
                    <system_config_backend_sitemap>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_System_Config_Backend_Sitemap</system_config_backend_sitemap>
                    <query>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query</query>
                    <session>Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Session</session>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Obviously I'd rather not have to define each one of these, but I just can't get the other classes from the "parent" module to fallthrough correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding this to your `config.xml`:

```
    <models>
        <catalogsearch>
            <class>Company_CatalogSearch_Model</class>
        </catalogsearch>
    </models>
```

You are telling Magento that each time you call `Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/something_here')` it will look for the model class in `Company/CatalogSearch/Model/Something/Here.php`.

And there are a lot of calls to `Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/...')`.

Since you only added one model and you need that to be instantiated when you call

```
Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/system_config_listSort');
```

You can do one of the following.
In both of them you need to remove the `<models>` tag from `config.xml` and replace with something else.

**Option 1.** - quick and dirty.

```
<models>
    <catalogsearch>
        <rewrite>
            <system_config_listSort>Company_CatalogSearch_Model_System_Config_ListSort</system_config_listSort>
        </rewrite>
    </catalogsearch>
</models>
```

Even if you are apparently rewriting an unexisting model it will still work.

**Option 2**  - clean

Change the prefix of your models.

```
 <models>
    <company_catalogsearch><!-- this instead of 'catalogsearh' -->
        <class>Company_CatalogSearch_Model</class>
    </company_catalogsearch>
</models>
```

Then, when you need an instance of your model just make it like this

```
Mage::getModel('company_catalogsearch/system_config_listSort');
```

Instead of

```
Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/system_config_listSort');
```

Comment: I swear I tried option 1, but I guess I got something about it wrong. I also tried option 2, but didn't realize I needed to update the getModel call. Very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the problem is in these lines of your config.xml

```
   <models>
        <catalogsearch>
            <class>Company_CatalogSearch_Model</class>
        </catalogsearch>
    </models>
```

I think it should be

```
   <models>
        <catalogsearch>
            <class>Company_CatalogSearch_Model_System_Config_ListSort</class>
        </catalogsearch>
    </models>
```

Well, I think there should be something after the text `Model` otherwise you are telling Magento that you are rewriting the entire family of classes '`Company_CatalogSearch_Model_*`' (as confirmed by your analysis above).